# MarshalAs: SizeConst must be actually +1? (With Repro case)

Tags: c#, marshalling

I am trying to use the marshalling thing correctly to serialize 4 bytes into a string.
When reading about [SizeConst](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.interopservices.marshalasattribute.sizeconst(v=vs.110).aspx), it states

> Indicates the number of elements in the fixed-length array or the number of characters (not bytes) in a string to import.

So I assumed that to read four bytes as string I require the following struct for marshalling

```
    struct Data
    {
        [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValTStr, SizeConst = 4)]
        public string string4;
    }
```

However it appears for some reason that I need `SizeConst` to set to 5 to get the 4 bytes.

Here is some example

```
    public void Test_Marshal()
    {
        var file = @"D:\foo.bin" ;
        var chars = new char[] {'W', 'H', 'A','T', '?'};

        File.WriteAllBytes(file, chars.ToList().Select( c => Convert.ToByte(c)).ToArray());


        var fileAsStream = new FileStream(file, FileMode.Open);

        int count = Marshal.SizeOf(typeof(Data));
        byte[] readBuffer = new byte[count];

        using (var reader = new BinaryReader(fileAsStream))
        {
            readBuffer = reader.ReadBytes(count);
        }

        GCHandle handle = GCHandle.Alloc(readBuffer, GCHandleType.Pinned);
        var aStruct = (Data)Marshal.PtrToStructure(handle.AddrOfPinnedObject(), typeof(Data));
        handle.Free();

        System.Diagnostics.Debug.Assert(aStruct.string4 == "WHAT");
    }
```

What I do: I write "WHAT?" in bytes into a file.
I then read the file and marshal the data into a struct with a member set to contain a fixed array of 4.
But I only get `WHA`, which are three chars and I do not understand why. If it would be C/C++ I would assume I need some null-termination but I am unaware of this condition in C#

What is happening here?

Comment: This is designed to support marshaling data to native code with pinvoke.  Such code expects a C string, it requires an extra character to store the zero-terminator.  So your current declaration could store only a 3 character string.  Also note that the data you wrote does not match the layout of the struct, so it only *seems* like you could write a longer string to the file.  That turns ugly when you write multiple structs.  .NET has multiple ways to serialize data, this one should not be on the top of your list.

Comment: @HansPassant it only seems because sizeof string is 4 byte? And I should use explicit layout instead? Besides that: Thank you for the explanation.

Comment: No, no.  This tends to only ever get to a good end when you understand pinvoke and C declarations well enough.  There is a huge billboard on the wall behind you, it says "don't do it".

Comment: @HansPassant, what would you suggest to read the header data of a binary file like a .dds? (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/direct3ddds/dds-header)

Comment: @Samuel I don't see any strings in that header definition. Just a bunch of DWORDs and a sub struct that only contains DWORDS

Comment: I cannot guess what that might have to do with this question.  No strings.  So anything I'd say would probably be very misleading, better if I don't.  Be sure to talk about the real problem you are trying to solve when you ask for help.

Comment: @ScottChamberlain you are right of course. I missed to point out that there is a sub-struct in the file (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/direct3ddds/dds-pixelformat) that has a field `DWORD dwFourCC` which are four bytes depicting text like "DXT1" or "DXT5" and to avoid having 4 uint in my code I wanted to directly marshal those four bytes into a System.String, which by using the mechanism above would require to have a SizeConst==5 instead of 4, which lead me to this question. I assume there are better solutions to that which I have yet to find.